# ASP.NET vNext. General editor template

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 5 I can customize general Editor Template by creating custom Object.cshtml.

But I can't find such behavior in MVC 6 beta8.

Question: How I can customize general editor template in MVC 6?

**UPDATED:**

Seems this functionality is harcoded. [DefaultEditorTemplates.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/ccfd235f5017178b88c15ff3b0ddb0a28cefbaa6/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/DefaultEditorTemplates.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Based on DefaultEditorTemplates class I've made my TagHelper.

Maybe for someone it will be useful.

ModelTagHelper.cs

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = ForAttributeName)]
public class ModelTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    protected const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";
    protected const string ObjectViewPath = "~/Views/Shared/Object.cshtml";

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public override int Order => -1000;

    protected object Model => For.Model;

    protected IHtmlGenerator HtmlGenerator { get; }
    protected IViewEngine ViewEngine { get; }
    protected ITempDataProvider TempDataProvider { get; }
    protected IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; }

    public ModelTagHelper(
        ICompositeViewEngine viewEngine, 
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        HtmlGenerator = generator;
        ViewEngine = viewEngine;
        TempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected virtual ActionContext CreateActionContext() => new ActionContext(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    protected virtual ViewDataDictionary CreateViewDataDictionary() => new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary());

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        if (output == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(output));
        }

        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewDataDictionary = CreateViewDataDictionary();
            viewDataDictionary.Model = Model;

            var actionContext = CreateActionContext();
            var viewResult = ViewEngine.FindPartialView(actionContext, ObjectViewPath);
            if (!viewResult.Success)
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Cannot find the file", ObjectViewPath);
            }
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                viewResult.View,
                viewDataDictionary,
                new TempDataDictionary(HttpContextAccessor, TempDataProvider),
                sw, new HtmlHelperOptions { ClientValidationEnabled = true });
            viewResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext).Wait();
            sw.Flush();

            output.Content.SetContent(new HtmlString(sw.ToString()));
        }
    }

}
```

Object.cshmtl

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures
@{
var tplInfo = ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo;

Func<ModelExplorer, TemplateInfo, bool> ShouldShow =
    (modelExplorer, templateInfo) =>
    modelExplorer.Metadata.ShowForEdit &&
    !modelExplorer.Metadata.IsComplexType &&
    !templateInfo.Visited(modelExplorer);

var properties = from property in ViewData.ModelExplorer.Properties
                 let propertyMetadata = property.Metadata
                 where ShouldShow(property, tplInfo)
                 select propertyMetadata;

}
@foreach (var propertyMetadata in properties)
{
if (propertyMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml)
{
    @Html.Editor(propertyMetadata.PropertyName)
}
else
{
    var label = Html.Label(propertyMetadata.PropertyName, labelText: null, htmlAttributes: null);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(label.ToString()))
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
            @label
        </div>
    }
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.Editor(propertyMetadata.PropertyName)
        @Html.ValidationMessage(propertyMetadata.PropertyName)
    </div>
}
}
```

MyView.cshtml

```
<div asp-for="@Model"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net-5 brings a new feature called "TagHelpers".

You see them at work in the default MVC6 shared _Layout.cshtml page with the 'environment' tags that produce different output depending on the run-time environment - Development, Staging, Production etc.

You'll see the 'Microsoft.AspNet.MVC.TagHelpers..." package loaded inside both DNX 4.5.1 and DNX Core 5.0 framework sections within the 'references' sections in Solution Explorer.

It looks as if TagHelpers are designed as a replacement to 'Templates'.

A quick overview here: [Wildermuth](http://wildermuth.com/2015/9/14/A_Look_at_ASP_NET_5_Part_4_-_MVC_6)

And two articles more in-depth: [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/08/06/a-complete-guide-to-the-mvc-6-tag-helpers.aspx) and [MSDN Mag](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/08/04/asp-net-mvc-6-part-1-tag-helpers.aspx) - 2 part article

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Tag helpers are not designed as a replacement to templates, but to using the `@Html`helpers and co. in HTML. In favor of HTML that is real XML.

Comment: ProfK -- not referring to 'Project Templates'; but, to the templates generated by @Html helpers as you point out.